# Displaying a tag's attributes in a tabular layout

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

In firebug (or firefox/chrome developer tools) is there any config/plugin to show attributes of an inspected tag in a tabular layout ( just like computed css rules)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://getfirebug.com/layout

Also, there is a similar GitHub issue for it, follow the thread for some solutions: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/6410

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. both links are unrelated to the question.

Comment: Never mind, I tried. Thanks for letting me know and not down voting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of an inspected tag, as well as other DOM properties applicable for that selected node are already listed in the developer tools panel.

In Chrome, switch to **Properties** tab and collapse the first item - which is actually your inspected tag.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

In Firebug, switch to **DOM** tab. A detailed list is available if you right-click on the DOM tab and select **Show DOM properties**.
[image: Firebug]

Comment: Thanks. I only need to seed the specified html attributes. That lists show all DOM properties of a node. Is there any way to hide properties with default value?

Answer (score 0):

However the chrome developer tools gives pretty much access to the tag management. You can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/access-log/foioongmhbfjnmiljihjgbkkaggodfao) to inspect the missing attributes of the inspected elements. Here's another one which allow you to compare the computed attributes.

You can do a little tweaking to make [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/pefnhibkhcfooofgmgoipfpcojnhhljm) work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the element in the **DOM Tree** on the **Elements** panel.
2. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to open the **Console**.
3. In the **Console**, run `$0.attributes`. `$0` is a reference to the currently-selected element.

[image: logging attributes in the console]